# Даны три вещественных числа,разделенные пробелами или переводами строк. Найти наибольшее из них

Tags: python

Как сделать чтобы программа работала,если ввести числа через пробел? Сама программа:

```
a = int(input("Введи число: "))
b = int(input("Введи число: "))
c = int(input("Введи число: "))
i = [a, b, c]
max_num = i[0]
for c in i:
    if max_num < c: max_num = c
print("Максимальное число: " + str(max_num))
```

Comment: у вас в задании говорится про вещественные числа. почему вы оперируете методом `int`?

Comment: почитайте про строковый метод split - и ваше задание легко решится.

Comment: `a, b, c = input().split()`

Comment: @Danis лучше будет a, b, c = map(int, input().split())

Comment: @mazzz3r да почему `int`-то?

Comment: Не увидел, что число вещественное, смотрел только на код. Тогда само собой `a, b, c = map(float, input().split())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого начало вашего кода обязано быть таким:

```
inp = input("Введите числа через пробел: ")
i = inp.split(" ")
```

`str.split(separator)`

- выводом является список
- `str` это строка, которую нужно разделить
- `separator` это символ разделения.

Comment: Это ж для случая когда все в строку.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение вводить строки и разбивать их на слова, пока слов не будет достаточно. Затем слова преобразуются в числа и отыскивается максимальное:

```
words = []
while len(words) < 3:
    words.extend(input().split())
print(max(map(float, words)))
```